# to do something back - grammar

Tags: grammar

I found these lyrics interesting.

> If I told you that I miss you, would you tell me that you miss me back?

It is not obvious to me the verb that 'back' is modifying. Is it that the other person "misses me back" or would the other person "tell me *something* back"? Is this even grammatical? I cannot find anything on the web about "doing something back," as in "in return for something."

Thanks.

Comment: It's an idiomatic but informal usage.  Probably originally used in sentences such as "If you hit me then I'll hit you back."

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks for the comment. Is is grammatically coherent? I found multiple entries for "to hit back" as a verb, but none for "to tell back."

Comment: Like I said it's informal, but would be readily understood by a native (US) English speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the author has used his poetic license to rephrase "would you tell me back that you miss me"

Comment: I see. Do you believe it is correct grammatically? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, of course. _That you miss me_ is the direct object of _tell back_, a phrasal verb like _look up_ which can either take the direct object between the verb and the particle, or keep the verb and particle together with the direct object right afterwards. Very ordinary construction, just a little longer and more awkward than usual.

Comment: @JohnLawler A part of my confusion stems from the fact that I couldn't find entries for these verbs - tell back, miss back, etc - in dictionaries. Could you please provide a reference link?

Comment: Well, they often won't be in dictionaries. This is a construction with a number of parts, and the phrasal verb is only part of it. It's more the usage of reciprocal behavior with _back_. It's common to say "A does X to B, and B does Y back to A", whether it's fighting or gifting. The _back_ implies a reciprocality of action and is not part of a simple verb+particle construction.

Comment: Yes, it is grammatically correct and I consider it an extension of  "give it back" because love feels better when reciprocated (or _loved back_).

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze the part **tell me that you miss me back**

*tell* is a transitive verb here and like transitive verbs are wont to take objects, it takes *me* as its direct object. So far so good.

What about *that you miss me back*? What role does it play?

You tell someone *something*, right? (A lie, truth, etc.)

That *something* must be a *Noun Clause* or a *Noun Phrase*. Thus, *that you miss me back* has to be a *Noun Clause* here because it functions as a *mini-sentence* within a bigger sentence (that is, it has its own Subject and Predicate and carries meaning).

What about the syntax of the *Noun Clause* itself? Let's see:

As pointed out earlier, it has its own Subject and Predicate— *you* and *miss me back*, respectively.

Finally, concentrate on the bit **miss me back** . Again, the *transitive verb- direct object- modifier* combo. Clearly, *back* here modifies the verb *miss* as it tells us *something about the way in which the singer wants to be loved*:  *he wants his love to be reciprocated.* Thus, it serves as an adverb.

Comment: Dear downvoter, could you also cite the reason for downvoting  my answer? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. So "I miss you back" is a grammatically correct response, right? (I was told otherwise by a friend.) Also if 'back' can modify verbs, won't "tell me smth back" be a correct interpretation as well?